# Async resource pool

Tags: java, concurrency, netty, connection-pooling, lock-free

I am looking for a resource pool with fully non-blocking API, for pooling of Netty channels on client side. Netty's [ChannelPool](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/pool/ChannelPool.html) is fine, but it enforces writing into channel from the event loop [by design](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/7452). I want to get rid of the context-switch when the channel is already available, and maybe save a couple of future/promise allocations.

Since Netty does not provide anything out-of-the box, I am looking for a generic pool implementation. My ideal API would look like

```
interface Pool<T> {
   void acquire(Consumer<T> resourceConsumer);
   void release(T resource);
}
```

+ all the shutdown methods and resource factory hooks. When the resource is ready, the consumer would be called immediately. When the resource is not available, the consumer would be triggered probably in provided executor (as we don't want to chain invocations from `release` too much).

Is there something that would give me this? I know Apache Commons pool, HikariCP and some other specialized pools, but these follow the blocking `borrowObjectFromPool` pattern. I would prefer a lock-free variant, but lets leave such implementation detail up to the maturity of the project.